# How do I specify column names when using numpy loadtxt or genfromtxt?

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I have the following sample file (test.csv), the first row being the header:

```
#a  |b    |c
foo |fooo |foooo
bar |barr |barrr
```

The command:

```
numpy.loadtxt('test.csv', delimiter='|', dtype=str)
```

works just fine. The output is

```
array([['foo ', 'fooo ', 'foooo'],
       ['bar ', 'barr ', 'barrr']], dtype='<U5')
```

However if I try to specify names for the columns:

```
numpy.loadtxt('test.csv', delimiter='|', dtype=[('a', str), ('b', str), ('c', str)])
```

I get:

```
array([('', '', ''), ('', '', '')],
      dtype=[('a', '<U'), ('b', '<U'), ('c', '<U')])
```

Same with auto-inferring names using genfromtxt:

```
numpy.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter='|', names=True, dtype=str)
```

output

```
array([('', '', ''), ('', '', '')],
      dtype=[('a', '<U'), ('b', '<U'), ('c', '<U')])
```

even if the names are correctly identified.
What am I doing wrong? I am sure I am missing something obvious.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? In what way isn't `array([['foo ', 'fooo ', 'foooo'], ['bar ', 'barr ', 'barrr']], dtype='<U5')` what you want?

Comment: Explicitly specifying the length can solve the problem, but the principle is unclear: `np.loadtxt('test.csv', delimiter='|', dtype=[('a', '<U5'), ('b', '<U5'), ('c', '<U5')])`

Comment: @Filip I would like a structured array, where I can select columns by name.

Comment: @MechanicPig I don't understand why specifying the length is not required when not giving names to the columns.

Comment: With `dtype=str`, it infers the length, same as if you do `np.array([1,2,3],str)`.  But when specifying a compound dtype for a structured array there's no such inference `np.array([1,2,3],'U5,U3,int')`

Comment: A compound dtype has clear `itemsize`, that does not depend at all on the values: `np.dtype('U5,float,int').itemsize` is `32`.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [32]: txt='''#a  |b    |c
...: foo |fooo |foooo
...: bar |barr |barrr'''.splitlines()
```

With `dtype=None` `genfromtxt` can infer field dtypes;

```
In [36]: np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter='|', dtype=None, names=True, encoding=None)
Out[36]: 
array([('foo ', 'fooo ', 'foooo'), ('bar ', 'barr ', 'barrr')],
      dtype=[('a', '<U4'), ('b', '<U5'), ('c', '<U5')])
```

and with `names=True` it inferred the field names from the first line (comment or not)

Without names it's a 2d array (skipping the comment line):

```
In [37]: np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter='|', dtype=None, encoding=None)
Out[37]: 
array([['foo ', 'fooo ', 'foooo'],
       ['bar ', 'barr ', 'barrr']], dtype='<U5')
```

`genfromtxt` is quite flexible, but that requires a lot of parameters.  Basically it loads the data as list of lists (with strings separated by the delimiter).  It then builds the array from that.  So some understanding of how arrays are constructed from a list of lists and a dtype helps.

As I commented:

```
In [38]: np.dtype('U5,float,int').itemsize
Out[38]: 32
In [39]: np.array((1,2,3),np.dtype('U5,float,int'))
Out[39]: array(('1', 2., 3), dtype=[('f0', '<U5'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<i4')])

In [41]: np.array((1,2,3), str)
Out[41]: array(['1', '2', '3'], dtype='<U1')
```

### edit

Explicit field names:

```
In [42]: np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter='|', dtype=None, 
    names=['A','B','C'], encoding=None)
Out[42]: 
array([('foo ', 'fooo ', 'foooo'), ('bar ', 'barr ', 'barrr')],
      dtype=[('A', '<U4'), ('B', '<U5'), ('C', '<U5')])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist of using numpy, then you can do the following:

```py
import np as np
arr = np.recfromcsv('text.csv', delimiter='|', encoding='utf-8', dtype=None)
```

```py
arr2 = np.array(
    [
        ('foo ', 'fooo ', 'foooo'),
        ('bar ', 'barr ', 'barrr'),
    ],
    dtype=[('a', '<U4'), ('b', '<U5'), ('c', '<U5')],
)

> print(all(arr == arr2))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with column names, I suggest using pandas instead.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='|')
```

And if you want to fix the leading and trailing spaces in the column names and values, you can do the following:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='|')
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df = df.applymap(str.strip)
```

```py
> print(df)

    #a     b      c
0  foo  fooo  foooo
1  bar  barr  barrr
```

Comment: That works, but I was also curious to understand what is going on with the pure numpy functions.

Comment: Give polars a shot instead of pandas if you're not already highly invested in pandas.